# AttributeError while trying to call a contract using web3py and Infura

Tags: contract-invocation, web3.py, infura

I am trying to call a function from an already-deployed contract on the Ropsten network:

```
from web3 import Web3


infura_url = "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))

ABI = '[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"say","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]'

contract_address = '0xF12f96cbc638E01546d9Ba3a1847BE762ea6dd4b'
contract = w3.eth.contract(contract_address, abi=ABI)

print('Return message from function: {}'.format(contract.say()))
```

My Infura key works, just tried to get the last block and balance of some random account. But I cannot interact with the contract despite giving the correct ABI and contract address? I also tried with:

- `contract.functions().say()`
- `contract.functions.say()`

But I am always getting an `AttributeError`?

Comment: hmm I may also need the bytecode or compile the .sol before locally with truffle? According to this long tutorial: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/dapps-development-for-python-developers-f52b32b54f28

Comment: In web3.py v4, try `contract.transact({'from': ..., 'gas': ..., 'gasPrice': ...}).say()`.

Answer (score 1):

You were close with your final attempt, you just need to call the `call()` method as well. The proper syntax is:

```py
contract.functions.say().call()
```

See the related [`web3.py` documentation](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.ContractFunction.call) for more information.

Comment: You may also need to specify the caller depending on the function. `contract.functions.say().call({'from': ''0x......})`.
`

Comment: ok thanks guys will try now but this may be a bigger issue - I have old web3 version (3.6.15) as well as "unholly" way to compile Python modules as I manually installed VC++ build tools...hope none of this messes with the processes. If it's just coding issue I'll try as Molina suggests and specify account source.